# Cannot send forgot password email in Ghost

Tags: nodemailer, ghost-blog, ghost

I received an error saying 'Error: Greeting never received'

My settings in `config.js`

```
mail: {
    transport: 'SMTP',
    options: {
        host: 'smtp.mxhichina.com',
        port: 465,
        secure: true,
        auth: {
            user: '......',
            pass: '......'
        }
    }
},
```

Comment: what os are you using?

Answer (score 0):

In case you are running a *nix system, you could proceed as follows to setup your local mail sender for ghost. Run the command:
`which sendmail`

it could give you the output:
`/usr/sbin/sendmail`

then add this to your config.js file:

```
mail: {
  transport: 'SMTP',
  options: {
    service: 'Sendmail',
    debug: true

}
```

The configuration you are using requires you open an account in the service you are using, that's why you need to provide authorization. Sendmail is a great solution for local environment, for further ghost mail configs have a look at [this](https://www.ghostforbeginners.com/how-to-configure-ghost-to-send-email/) article